# Express body parser entire request body is key with no value

Tags: ios, node.js, express, body-parser

I want to get values the body in a post using express node.js and an iOS client. Here is my server code:

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.firstName)
})
```

On the client here is what I'm doing with the json body:

```
let json = ["firstName": "First Dude",
                "lastName": "Last dude"]
    let body = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
```

When I hit the endpoint I get:

```
{ '{"lastName":"Last dude","firstName":"First Dude"}': '' }
undefined
```

Which looks like the key is the entire json body and the value is empty.

`req.body.firstName` is also undefined.

How can I get a value from a key using body parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the content type to the request and to the `body-parser`.

`request.setValue(application/json, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`
`app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exacly

> models.User

is ?

But In this part :

```
app.post('/user', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log(req.body.firstName)
  var user = models.User.create({
      firstName: req.body.firstName,
      lastName: req.body.lastName,
     id: uuidV1(),
  });
  res.send(user.toJSON())
})
```

You should write

> res.json(user.toJSON())

instead of

> res.send(user.toJSON())

Comment: Thanks, that helps, I was hoping someone would help me with that. I'm going to slim down my question to just show what I'm needing. Thanks!

Comment: Enjoy :)) Please just vote up if it really helps you.